# Parralax effect on Safari not working properly

Tags: javascript, safari, parallax

I have a portfolio website and when I tried it on Safari it appears that on scroll the parallax effect with the bubble doesn't work properly (see snapshot bellow)

[Animation with bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05mMb.jpg)

[Animation without buggy effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u76hQ.jpg)

I don't have access to a Mac easily so it's quite difficult for me to debug this thing.

The parrallax code of this is :

```
// PARALLAX ANIMATION
class Parallax {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element
        this.ratio = parseFloat(element.dataset.parallax)
        this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this)
        this.onIntersection = this.onIntersection.bind(this)
        this.elementY = offsetTop(this.element) + this.element.offsetHeight / 2
        new IntersectionObserver(this.onIntersection).observe(element)
        this.onScroll()
    }
    onIntersection(entries) {
        for (const entry of entries) {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) {
                document.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll)
                this.elementY = offsetTop(this.element) + this.element.offsetHeight / 2

            } else {
                document.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll)
            }

        }
        
    }
    onScroll() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            const screenY = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2
            const diffY = this.elementY - screenY;
            this.element.style.setProperty(
                "transform",
                `translateY(${-1 * diffY * this.ratio}px)`)
        })
    }
    static bind() {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-parallax]')).map(
            (element) => {
                return new Parallax(element)
            }
        )
    }
}
Parallax.bind()
```

The link to the portfolio is : https://manonbruimaud.fr

The link to the GitHub of the project: https://github.com/manonBr/manonbruimaud/tree/main

At first, I thought about some CSS properties that Safari don't handle the way other browsers do, but it's not.
It seems that the `<div>` is moving but all the effects (radius, etc) stay in the original position. So I'm thinking about performance issues in my `.js`

Someone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

**Solution:**

If that can help someone, it was in fact some CSS issues on safari. Blur is not handle well. I just added a `will-change: transform` on the element and now it's working!